# how to initialize a map in flutter/dart with widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

what i am trying to is have containers widget to have unique id so that i can uniquely identify them i have tried :

```
  Map<int,Container> box={
    1:Container(),
    2:Container(),
    3:Container(),
  };
```

---

```
  Map<int,Widget> box={
    1:Container(),
    2:Container(),
    3:Container(),
  };
```

---

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children:<Widget> [
          box[1],
        ],
      ),
```

---

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children:[
          box[1],
        ],
      ),
```

---

### tried both

is there any way to do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use  `List<Widget>`

Define:

```
List<Widget> list = [Container(), Container(), Container()];
```

Use:

```
Column(
  children: [list[0]],
);
```

Comment: It works but the i cannot access any of the containers property like color of the container i have to set it at the time of initializing.can i access these properties with the list variable we have made